# PS2: Installing fast MC boot without CD?

Tags: ps2

I own a **SCPH-39004 FAT PlayStation 2**. Its optic drive does not work. Is there any way to install fast MC boot without having to use a CD? I mean by using one of the ps2's usb slots or maybe by a ps1 as I have one.

Answer (score 1):

First I can tell you it is possible for you to install freemcboot on a memory card, with the noobie package as well if it is empty, from a different not broken ps2,just make sure to use the universal installer...

also as this is a phat system if you have a network adapter for it ($7) or so online) and a computer with an open pata/ide port and a spare drive it is possible to install freehdboot to almost any size of these older drives I think up to 500gb ive heard...
you can also buy a usb to ide adapter and do it that way but you will still need to have a means to power it as well....

this often involves formatting the drive to a speciffic type then using a special program to burn an image to the drive...its been a while since I had to do it though so I dont recall all the details of the names...but with a second program you can load the iso files from your disks to the drive from your computer so the dead laser problem shouldnt be an issue....

Comment: Do NOT advertise your products here.

Comment: ive got 30 that have been sitting on a shelf over a year now...and have 20more that I can configure to work ...I can just as easilly rightfully post the product on amazon and give a link saying you can buy preloaded drives here so dont give me needless slack....

Comment: No.  If you advertise your products here, I *will* be flagging the post as spam.  They have literally *zero* relevance to your answer.

Comment: the answer was accepted by the user already including the statement i have them available and he can email me on it if interested I mearly added content in parentheses  to specify....quite frankly @frank your destroying these forums ive had trouble with you already and your little more than a troll and the primary reason why they should never allow users to be reaponsible for content being allowed to persist....get a life and quit trying to ruin everyone elses...and it is relevent that he can simply buy something that will work instead of having to search many programs....

Comment: A) The asker has not accepted your answer.  B) Arqade is *community* moderated.  We have quality standards here.  Standards that you're not really meeting very well.  C) Linking your own products isn't relevant; it has *nothing* to do with answering the question.  Focus on solving the problem.  "Hey, I have a drive to sell that will fix this" isn't solving it; it's advertising your product.